# Comparing two aspect ratios

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to compare two aspect ratios in Javascript. 
I have two ratios 12:3 and 12:2 and I need to compare both.

```
if(12:3 > 12:2) {
   console.log(true);
}
```

What would be a good approach to doing this?

Comment: Divide them, compare the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply divide them, that will give you the ratio...

```js
if((12/3) > (12/2)) {
    console.log(true);
} else {
    console.log(false); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply divide them by each other as user *caramba* described:

```
const ratioA = 12/3; // 12:3
const ratioB = 12/2; // 12:2
const sameRatio = ratioA === ratioB // is ratioA the same as ratioB?
```

... but sometimes you may be looking to compare values that are close but not quite there.

```
const aspectRatios = [16/9, 4/3, 1/1] // 16:9, 4:3, 1:1
```

For that you should do something like:

```
// The number here respresents accuracy. Low-accuracy is good. 
// The lower the accuracy, the higher chance we have of getting a close match.
const makeComparisonFloat = (float) => Math.round(float * 10) 
const ratio = makeComparisonFloat(width / height)
return aspectRatios.find((option) => makeComparisonFloat(option.ratio) === ratio)
```